# How bypassing AccessorGetter interceptors in V8::Object

Tags: visual-c++, v8

how can i bypassing AccessorGetter interceptor?

```
Handle<FunctionTemplate> mars_obj_templ = FunctionTemplate::New(createMars);  
Handle<ObjectTemplate> mars_obj_proto = mars_obj_templ->PrototypeTemplate();  
Handle<ObjectTemplate> mars_obj_inst = mars_obj_templ->InstanceTemplate();  
mars_obj_inst->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
mars_obj_inst->SetAccessor(String::New("name"),GetName,SetName);

Handle<Value> GetName(Local<String> property,const AccessorInfo &info){
    Local<Object> self = info.Holder();
    //return what, if self->Get(property) will Recursive call
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience you can't. But if you register a general Interceptor using `SetNamedPropertyHandler` on `ObjectTemplate` you can safely call `self->Get` without ending up in recursion.
Comparing the requested properties with the ones you're interested in, you can handle them and just forward the other calls.

Comment: what is you mean use SetNamedPropertyHandler instead of SetAccessor? OK, I'll have a test.

Comment: Exactly this is what I suggest.

Comment: Yes, I fined is can't, so I don't use this Feature。